# can not connection with api by retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, themoviedb-api

I want create movies app , which shows a list of movies in recycler view , i use retrofit library for call api movies DB , in the MainActivity i use try and catch if the request is empty print "Please obtain API Key firstly from themoviedb.org" , and on onFailure() method print error message , put when i run my app nothing appear ! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xldN.png)

my ActivityMain

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter adapter;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = MoviesAdapter.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                initViews();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Movies Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    public Activity getActivity() {
        Context context = this;
        while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
            if (context instanceof Activity) {
                return (Activity) context;
            }
            context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
        }
        return null;

    }

    private void initViews() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Feitching Movies..");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, movieList);
        if (getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
        }
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    private void loadJSON() {


        try {
            if (BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please obtain API Key firstly from themoviedb.org", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pd.dismiss();
                return;
            }
            Client Client = new Client();
            Service apiService =
                    Client.getClient().create(Service.class);
            Call<MoviesResponse> call = apiService.getPopularMovies(BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
                    List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
                    Collections.sort(movies, Movie.BY_NAME_ALPHABETICAL);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movies));
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                    if (swipeContainer.isRefreshing()){
                        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }




                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Fetching Data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }
            });


        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

my detailActivity  class

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nameOfMovie, plotSynopsis, userRating, releaseDate;
    ImageView imageView;
    Movie movie;
    String thumbnail, movieName, synopsis, rating, dateOfRelease;
    int movie_id;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detial);

        initCollapsingToolbar();

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_image_header);
        nameOfMovie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        plotSynopsis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plotsynopsis);
        userRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userrating);
        releaseDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.releasedate);

        Intent intentThatStartedThisActivity = getIntent();
        if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra("Original_title")) {


            String thumbnail = getIntent().getExtras().getString("poster_path");
            String movieName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("original_title");
            String synopsis =getIntent().getExtras().getString("overview");
            String rating =getIntent().getExtras().getString("realese_date");


            String poster = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + thumbnail;

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(poster)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.load)
                    .into(imageView);

            nameOfMovie.setText(movieName);
            plotSynopsis.setText(synopsis);
            userRating.setText(rating);
            releaseDate.setText(dateOfRelease);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No API Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getString(R.string.movie_details));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

movie class

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by delaroy on 5/18/17.
 */
public class Movie implements Parcelable {
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String posterPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    private boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    private String releaseDate;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    private Integer voteCount;
    @SerializedName("video")
    private Boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    private Double voteAverage;

    public Movie(String posterPath, boolean adult, String overview, String releaseDate, List<Integer> genreIds, Integer id,
                 String originalTitle, String originalLanguage, String title, String backdropPath, Double popularity,
                 Integer voteCount, Boolean video, Double voteAverage) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
        this.adult = adult;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
        this.id = id;
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
        this.title = title;
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
        this.popularity = popularity;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        this.video = video;
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public Movie(){

    }

    public static final Comparator<Movie> BY_NAME_ALPHABETICAL = new Comparator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Movie movie, Movie t1) {

            return movie.originalTitle.compareTo(t1.originalTitle);
        }
    };

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return  posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public boolean isAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public Boolean getVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public Double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.posterPath);
        dest.writeByte(this.adult ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
        dest.writeString(this.overview);
        dest.writeString(this.releaseDate);
        dest.writeList(this.genreIds);
        dest.writeValue(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.originalTitle);
        dest.writeString(this.originalLanguage);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeString(this.backdropPath);
        dest.writeValue(this.popularity);
        dest.writeValue(this.voteCount);
        dest.writeValue(this.video);
        dest.writeValue(this.voteAverage);
    }

    protected Movie(Parcel in) {
        this.posterPath = in.readString();
        this.adult = in.readByte() != 0;
        this.overview = in.readString();
        this.releaseDate = in.readString();
        this.genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        in.readList(this.genreIds, Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.id = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.originalTitle = in.readString();
        this.originalLanguage = in.readString();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.backdropPath = in.readString();
        this.popularity = (Double) in.readValue(Double.class.getClassLoader());
        this.voteCount = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.video = (Boolean) in.readValue(Boolean.class.getClassLoader());
        this.voteAverage = (Double) in.readValue(Double.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Movie(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };
}
```

interface :

```
public interface Service {



        @GET("movie/popular")
        Call<MoviesResponse> getPopularMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);

        @GET("movie/top_rated")
        Call<MoviesResponse> getTopRatedMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);



}
```

Comment: what is the error can you put it in description?

Comment: can you share your model ie your Moive bean and the api Interface, how you are creating them. and the JSON which you are getting in response .this snippet is fine

Comment: @Ashwani http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8f5f6df0585d0d2b95c786ab35858e78 this JSON data , and i'm added the interface

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal i don't have error but i can not show the movie

Comment: Did you debugged your code?

Comment: For reference i am attaching my answer

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code you might be getting response, anyhow, what worked for me is:

**MovieResponse.java**

```
public class MovieResponse {
    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private Integer page;
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalResults;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalPages;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Movie> results = null;

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public Integer getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public List<Movie> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Movie> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
public class Movie {
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer voteCount;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    private Boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    private Double voteAverage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    private String posterPath;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> genreIds = null;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    private Boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    private String releaseDate;

    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public Double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public Boolean getAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

}
```

**APIClient.java**

```
public class APIClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("movie/popular")
    Call<MovieResponse> getPopularMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);

}
```

**My method in activity java**

```
 private void getMovies(){
        ApiInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<MovieResponse> call = apiInterface.getPopularMovies("8f5f6df0585d0d2b95c786ab35858e78");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                if(response.body() != null){
                    movies = response.body().getResults();//place a breakpoint here in your code and check whether you are getting anything or not.
                    movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(movies, Main.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
                    Log.d("Movie","List Size: "+movies.size());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Movie","Error in fetching result");
            }
        });
    }
```